# Is there a way to determine when a spreadsheet is done calculating?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a spreadsheet with a lot of imports and formulas based on the imports.  Sometimes it takes a long time to update -- there is now a progress bar in the upper right that pops ups the message "calculating formulas" when you hover over it.  It there a programmatic way to detect when the sheet is done recalculating?

I'd like to popup a box (toast?) saying the sheet is busy and then disappear the box when the sheet is done recalculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. 
Volatile functions like Importrange are the enemies of spreadsheet stability. Sometimes they get stuck recalculating and never finish; that is for nor particular reason as creating a copy usually creates a version that finishes calculating (eventually).

If you work with many importrange formulas and formulas based on them it is generally advisable to replace the import formula by a scheduled import via script.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a dozen or so import range statements.  Not quite sure how to go about scheduling the import via a script.

Comment: Can't even edit my comment, :-(  5 seconds is not very long.  Anyway, use range.copyTo in a script set up as an event on a timer?

Comment: Which method you use depends on whether you want a whole sheet, its data or just a range copied. The approach you outlined below seems fine. You can wrap that into a function so you don't need to retype all the API calls everytime and just call it with the source url, sheet, range and target sheet

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work so far:

```
        SourceWB = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/185XVLyN4fFLds8Z7JIgkL6mGl1CC82maBmmVAhYP71g/");
SourceRange = SourceWB.getRangeByName("CoreElementExport");
SouceValues = SourceRange.getValues();
var sourceRows = SourceRange.getNumRows();
var sourceColumns = SourceRange.getNumColumns();

DestWB = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
DestSheet = DestWB.getSheetByName("TaxonomyImport");
DestSheet.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, sourceRows, sourceColumns).setValues(SouceValues);
```

something after, just trying to use this very complicated input tech...